# Can't create new environments, with CondaVerificationError: The package for ncurses is corrupted

Tags: conda, miniconda

I'm getting this error when trying to create new environment. IE

```
conda create -n jupyter python=3.6 -y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for ncurses located at /Users/yaroslavvb/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'share/terminfo/69/iTerm.app'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for ncurses located at /Users/yaroslavvb/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'share/terminfo/69/iTerm2.app'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

Any suggestions?

I tried the following things with no success (conda 4.5.11)

```
conda update -n base conda
conda update conda
conda install -f conda
conda install -f ncurses -y
conda update ncurses
conda uninstall ncurses -y
```

I'm using ITerms on a regular basis, my suspicion is that iterm auto-updated itself and broke some paths

Comment: Had the same also. Try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also ran into a similar problem as yours today. Here is my solution:
As it showed something cannot be found in this package, and we can't uninstall `ncurses` using `conda uninstall ncurses` command, I just removed this package manually:
(In your situation, it should be as following)

```sh
rm -r /Users/yaroslavvb/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0
```

and then we can install `ncurses` with specifying it's version and build which we just removed:

```sh
conda install ncurses=6.1=h0a44026_0
```

By the way, my error information pointed to `/path/to/miniconda2/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-hf484d3e_1002`, so I just removed this folder and reinstall it with a slightly modified command.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ncurses package was just broken (6.1-h0a44026_0), the current version seems to work