# Conda environment creation: can't create conda environment because of the CondaVerificationError

Tags: python, anaconda, repository, environment

I have a private python repository that my client's can download packages. Linux client can install packages from this private repository without any problem.

Linux client conda version: **4.3.30**

Windows client however, can't install the packages from the private repository.

Windows client conda version: **4.3.30**

The error was: `CondaVerificationError: The package for ncurses located at C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\ncurses-6.1-he6710b0_1 appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/terminfo' specified in the package manifest cannot be found.`

Than I do:

```
conda clean -all
```

After that command, when I try to install something, it gives no error and start installing bunch of stuff. After a while, it no longer continues to install (when it reaches the "pip-18.1-py37_"). Also it never close the installation process. It stucks in installing process.

```
 C:\Anaconda3\envs>conda create -n myenv3 python -y
Fetching package metadata .....
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda3\envs\myenv3:
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
    ca-certificates: 2018.12.5-0             http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    certifi:         2018.11.29-py37_0       http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    libedit:         3.1.20181209-hc058e9b_0 http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    libffi:          3.2.1-hd88cf55_4        http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    libgcc-ng:       8.2.0-hdf63c60_1        http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    libstdcxx-ng:    8.2.0-hdf63c60_1        http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    ncurses:         6.1-he6710b0_1          http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    openssl:         1.1.1a-h7b6447c_0       http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    pip:             18.1-py37_0             http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    python:          3.7.2-h0371630_0        http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    readline:        7.0-h7b6447c_5          http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    setuptools:      40.6.3-py37_0           http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    sqlite:          3.26.0-h7b6447c_0       http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    tk:              8.6.8-hbc83047_0        http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    wheel:           0.32.3-py37_0           http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    xz:              5.2.4-h14c3975_4        http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
    zlib:            1.2.11-h7b6447c_3       http://<IP_address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
ca-certificate 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   4.33 MB/s
libgcc-ng-8.2. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01   6.00 MB/s
libstdcxx-ng-8 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   7.78 MB/s
libffi-3.2.1-h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   5.95 MB/s
ncurses-6.1-he 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  10.38 MB/s
openssl-1.1.1a 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  10.58 MB/s
xz-5.2.4-h14c3 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  12.11 MB/s
zlib-1.2.11-h7 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  11.55 MB/s
libedit-3.1.20 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  10.21 MB/s
readline-7.0-h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  10.90 MB/s
tk-8.6.8-hbc83 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   7.70 MB/s
sqlite-3.26.0- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   9.85 MB/s
python-3.7.2-h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:04   8.09 MB/s
certifi-2018.1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   6.63 MB/s
setuptools-40. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   9.94 MB/s
wheel-0.32.3-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   5.01 MB/s
pip-18.1-py37_ 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   9.04 MB/s
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: After 1-2 hours, the loop ends and again I got the CondaVerificationError:

```
CondaVerificationError: The package for ncurses located at C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\ncurses-6.1-he6710b0_1
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/terminfo'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

EDIT 2: I tried to install another versions such as "5.3.1, 2018.12, 2019.03" but all of them failed while I try to create an environment and install packages with the above error:

```
    C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create -n myenv python`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Anaconda3
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\user
                     PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
                          Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Win
                          dows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1
                          .0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
                          Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\U
                          sers\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Anaconda3;
                          C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\user\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\user\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : http://<IP_Address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          http://<IP_Address>/PythonRepo/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
          package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\user\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\userAppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.15063
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]: N

No report sent. To permanently opt-out, use

    $ conda config --set report_errors false
```

Comment: Try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Comment: @G.Baysec -- did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the advice here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54761119/188963

i.e., I manually deleted ncurses folders:

```
find conda/envs -name "ncurses*" -exec rm -rf +
```

then

```
conda install ncurses=6.1
```

Afterwards, no problem.